# awk display variable with environment content

Tags: variables, awk, string-substitution

I'm getting from system one variable that returns a string, like:

```
$VARIABLE/dir/text.file
```

I tryed to use `gsub`, but I'm missing something:

```
onstat -c | grep ^MSGPATH | awk 'gsub (/$INFORMIXDIR/, ${INFORMIXDIR}) {print $2}'
```

It returns error:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: gsub (/$INFORMIXDIR/, ${INFORMIXDIR}) {print $2}
awk: cmd. line:1:                        ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: gsub (/$INFORMIXDIR/, ${INFORMIXDIR}) {print $2}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                     ^ 0 is invalid as number of arguments for gsub
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: do you have some of the output that onstat -c produces?

Comment: but do you want to print the variable value inside awk? or what?

Comment: it returns:$INFORMIXDIR/tmp/online.log and I need to use that value after, the INFORMIXDIR is one environment variable.

Comment: and what you need is to print the environment value for $INFORMIXDIR/tmp/online.log inside AWK, right?

Comment: yes I would like to have this value to use on my script

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use shell variables in an awk script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script)

Answer (score 2):

Because the awk body is in single quotes, you can't expand shell variables. The way to do this safely is to pass the value to awk with the `-v` option:

```
... | awk -v dir="$INFORMIXDIR" 'gsub (/\$INFORMIXDIR/, dir) {print $2}'
```

Note that you have to escape the `$` in the regular expression, because it is a special regex character (meaning "end of string")

Comment: Maybe avoid the regex escape and use `[$]` instead